# Solve $x^n \equiv -1 \ (mod \ p)$ given $n$ and prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Given $n$ and a prime $p$, I'd like to ask how to obtain all solutions to $x^n \equiv -1 \ (mod \ p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) to find $n$ind$_gx\equiv\dfrac{\phi(p)}2\pmod{\phi(p)}$  where $g$ is one of the primitive roots $\pmod p$

Now use [Linear Congruence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem).

**Generalization** : We can replace $p$ with any number that [has](https://brilliant.org/wiki/primitive-roots/#existence-of-primitive-roots) a primitive root.

Comment: Excuse me, could you illustrate more in detail?

Comment: @HangWu, Follow the links in the post and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124575/if-r-is-a-primitive-root-of-odd-prime-p-prove-that-textind-r-1-fr